# Why is d appearing as undefined in my d3 script?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**edited to include code where cell is defined**

I am attempting to create a chart that pulls data from an XHR request, but d is undefined in certain functions in my script:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 30, right: 40, bottom: 60, left: 40},
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatValue = d3.format(",d");


var x = d3.scaleTime()
//var x = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain([new Date(2017, 0, 1), new Date(2020, 11, 31)])
    //.rangeRound([0, width]);
    .range([0, width-300]);

    /*var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([new Date(2018, 0, 1), new Date(2020, 11, 31)])
      .range([50, 1150]);*/

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    // Define the div for the tooltip
    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 0);

//variables for legends
  var legendRectSize = 18;
  var legendSpacing = 4;

  
d3.request("https://api.parliament.uk/sparql?query=PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0APREFIX%20%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fid.parliament.uk%2Fschema%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20id%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fid.parliament.uk%2F%3E%0Aselect%20%3FTreaty%20%3FTreatyname%20%3FLeadOrg%20%3FSeries%20%3FLink%20%3FworkPackage%20%3FprocStepName%20%3Fdate%20where%20%7B%0A%20%3FTreaty%20a%20%3ATreaty%20.%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3FTreaty%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FTreatyname%20.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%20%3FTreaty%20%3AtreatyHasLeadGovernmentOrganisation%2F%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FLeadOrg%20.%7D%20%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3FTreaty%20%3AtreatyHasSeriesMembership%2F%20%3AseriesItemCitation%20%3FSeries.%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3FTreaty%20%3AworkPackagedThingHasWorkPackagedThingWebLink%20%3FLink.%7D%0A%09%3FTreaty%20%3AworkPackagedThingHasWorkPackage%20%3FworkPackage%20.%0A%20%20%09%3FworkPackage%20%3AworkPackageHasProcedure%2Frdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fproc%0A%20%20FILTER(%3Fproc%20IN%20(%22Treaties%20subject%20to%20the%20Constitutional%20Reform%20and%20Governance%20Act%202010%22))%0A%20%20%20%3FworkPackage%20%3AworkPackageHasBusinessItem%20%3FprocStep%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3FprocStep%20%3AbusinessItemDate%20%3Fdate%20.%0A%20%20%3FprocStep%20%3AbusinessItemHasProcedureStep%20id%3Acspzmb6w%20.%0A%20%20%3FprocStep%20%3AbusinessItemHasProcedureStep%2Frdfs%3Alabel%20%3FprocStepName.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A")
    .mimeType('application/sparql-results+json')
    .response(function(xhr) { return JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); })
    .get(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
var data1 = data.results.bindings;
  //if (error) alert(error);
  data1.forEach(function(d){
    d.datetrimmed = d.date.value.split('+')[0];
    console.log(d.datetrimmed)
  d.Date1 = Date.parse(d.datetrimmed)
  console.log(d.Date1)
  d.Date2 = d3.timeMonth(d.Date1)
  console.log(d.Date2)
  console.log(d.LeadOrg.value)
})
  x.domain(d3.extent(data.results.bindings, function(d) { return d.Date2; }));

var myColor = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(['#e6194b', '#3cb44b', '#ffe119', '#4363d8', '#f58231', '#911eb4', '#46f0f0', '#f032e6', '#bcf60c', '#fabebe', 'red', '#e6beff', '#9a6324', '#fffac8', '#800000']);

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
      .force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) { return x(d.Date2); }).strength(1))
      .force("y", d3.forceY(height / 2))
      .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(14))
      .stop();

  for (var i = 0; i < 120; ++i) simulation.tick();
  g.append("text")
          .attr("x", (width / 2))
          .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 5))
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .style("font-size", "24px")
          .style("font-family", "Tahoma")
          .style("text-decoration", "underline")
          .style("fill", "#f2f0f7")
          .text("All Treaties Subject to CRAG 2010 by Lead Organisation");

g.append("text")
        .attr("x", (width / 2))
        .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top - 45))
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font-size", "12px")
        .style("font-family", "Tahoma")
        .style("fill", "#f2f0f7")
        .text("Click a point on the chart or hover over a square on the legend to highlight all treaties from a given department");

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(20));

  g.append("text")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + (width/2-100) + " ," +
                            (height + margin.top + 10) + ")")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-size", "14px")
      .style("font-family", "Tahoma")
      .style("fill", "#f2f0f7")
      .text("Date the treaty was laid before the House of Commons");

  var cell = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "cells")
    .selectAll("g").data(d3.voronoi()
        .extent([[-margin.left, -margin.top], [width + margin.right, height + margin.top]])
        .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
        .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
      .polygons(data1)).enter().append("g");
```

The error occurs at this point further in, where it says that it cannot read property data of undefined:

```
cell.append("circle")
     .attr("class", function(d){
       console.log(d)
       org = d.data.results.bindings.LeadOrg.value;

       return org.replace(/[\s,]/g,'') })
```

Is there a way I should be defining d further in to the code?
This part of the code is still within the get request from the d3.request function. Is this going to cause problems?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of D3 are you using?

Comment: I'm using D3 version 4 and requests version 1.

Comment: Why would you expect `d` to have a `data` property? What do you get from `console.log(d)` in the `.attr` callback?

Comment: Please edit the question to add the portion of code where `cell` is defined, and data bound to it.

Comment: Hi @Mehdi, I've added that portion of the code and all the code that precedes it.

Answer (score 0):

You never pass the data from `cell` to `"circle"`. To do that, consider the following:

```js
cell.append("circle")
     .datum(function(d) { return d; })
     .attr("class", function(d){
       console.log(d)
       org = d.data.results.bindings.LeadOrg.value;

       return org.replace(/[\s,]/g,'') })
```

This takes the object `d` you assigned to `cell`, and returns it as the data object to assign to the circle as well.

Note that `.datum` is very related to `.data`, except that it expects one singular value, not an array of values.